# Best the best way to compare dates using ngIf in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am trying to compare dates in my app using ngIf, but I haven't been able to get it working properly so far.

```
<div *ngIf="(todaysdate | date:'MMM dd' == duedate | date:'MMM dd')">
List
</div>
```

I want to compare them using the date pipe because times on the full date string are different I only want to compare the dates. Any suggestions on how to properly do this are much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare works fine when you format your dates properly (eg. 20191224 for christmas). So this should work

```
<div *ngIf="(todaysdate | date:'yMMdd' == duedate | date:'yMMdd')">
    List
</div>
```

Comment: *ngIf="(todaysdate | date:'yMMdd') == (duedate | date:'yMMdd')"

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution is to `this.todaysdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` which you would do on your date prior in your constructor.

But you can also send it to and expression on the component `*ngIf="compareDates()"`

```
compareDates(){
   return this.todaysdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == this.duedate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for your answer, I tried it out and I get the following error Cannot read property 'setHours' of undefined

Comment: It has to be a Date() object. like `this.todaysdate = new Date();`

Answer (score 1):

A little extra but this is what I did based off the answer to compare expiration dates. Also, "expireDate" came as an object to I couldn't simply compare by two date objects.

.ts

```
today = new Date();
```

.html

```
<div *ngIf="(expireDate | date: 'yMMdd') > (today | date: 'yMMdd'); else template_Expired">
      {{ expireDate | date }}
</div>

<ng-template #template_Expired>
      <div class="expired">
        {{ expireDate | date }}
      </div>
</ng-template>
```

.css

```
.expired {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```